# Drawing a map on a jframe

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, graphics2d

I currently have a player rectangle that moves if an arrowkey gets pressed by the user. My next goal is to paint a map: 1 = walls(black rectangle), 0 = nothing(white rectangle). How do i implement that? The method for drawing the map is the drawmap2d method. This is my current code:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenu;



 
public class Raycast_World_2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{
    public int px,py;
    int velx = 0, vely = 0;
    Graphics f;
    int mapX=8,mapY=8,mapS=64;
    int map[]=
    {
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,    
    1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,     
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,     
    1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,     
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 
    1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1, 
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 
    };
    
    public Raycast_World_2()
    {
       px = 100;
        py = 100;
        setSize(1024,512);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        addKeyListener(this);
         setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        setTitle("Raycast_World-Try4_Version 3.0");
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu menuFile = new JMenu("File");
JMenuItem menuItemExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
menuFile.add(menuItemExit);
 
menuBar.add(menuFile);
 
// adds menu bar to the frame
setJMenuBar(menuBar);
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.gray);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        
        repaint();
    
    
}
    public void paint(java.awt.Graphics g) {
  super.paint(g);  
  g.setColor(Color.yellow);
  
  g.fillRect(px,py,6,6);
  g.dispose();
  drawMap2D(g);
  repaint();
}
public void drawMap2D(java.awt.Graphics g){
    int x,y,xo,yo;
    Color currentcolor;
    for(y=0;y<mapY;y++){
      for(x=0;x<mapX;x++){  
        xo = x*mapS;
        yo= y*mapS;
          if(map[y*mapX+x]==1){
            super.paint(g);
            currentcolor = Color.gray;
            g.setColor(currentcolor);
            g.fillRect(x,y,xo,yo);
            System.out.println("program tries to paint me");
        }else{
            super.paint(g);
            currentcolor = Color.white;
            g.setColor(currentcolor);
            g.fillRect(x,y,xo,yo);
            System.out.println("program tries to paint me");
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
    
}
}
```

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977613/drawing-lines-to-create-a-cell-in-java/46981554#46981554 for a working example. You just need to provide icons to represent the walls/nothing. I call them wall/floor in the example.

Comment: But the image is just a colored rectangle?

Comment: Then use a ColorIcon as demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415055/how-to-make-a-tile-in-java/38415190#38415190

Comment: `super.paint(g);` this should not be called from within a loop. Instead, make it the first statement called in the method.

Comment: BTW - rather than extending a frame and overriding `paint`, extend a `JPanel` and override `paintComponent`. Also override the `getPreferredSize` method to suggest a logical (presumably square) size then `pack` the frame to fit it perfectly to the size of the custom-painted panel (and any other components).